# spark-scala: Replace value in dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe of 32 colunms called `df1`, I want to do the steps below:

1. create `df2` that should take the first rows of `df1`
2. Change the value of `df2.region <- 'Madrid'`

I Tried:

```scala
val df1 = df.show(1)
```

Comment: What did you try so far ? Please do not expect people to do the work for you but rather show us what you have tried and what does not work as you expected.

Comment: The `show()` function does not return a new dataframe, it just display the content of the dataframe in a tabular form. use the `limit(n: Int)` instead to get the first n row (in your case n should be set to 1)

Comment: For the second part of your question, you can use `withColumn()` function to replace the value of the column region  `val df1 = df.withColumn("region", lit("Madrid")).limit(1)`

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following code

```
val df2 = d1.withColumn("region", lit("Madrid")).limit(1)
```